# Angular: Using $scope method in an object causes TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: angularjs

I'm getting the error: `TypeError: undefined is not a function` for this:

controller:

```
$scope.dateRange = { before: $scope.oneMonthAgo(), after: new Date }; #<------

$scope.oneMonthAgo = function oneMonthAgo() {
  var date = new Date;
  date.setMonth(date.getMonth() - 1);
  return date;
};
```

What's going on?? Is it because the object doesn't have access to the $scope method?

When I change it to this, it prints out the correct value for `oneMonthAgo()`:

```
    $scope.dateRange            = { before: new Date, after: new Date };


    $scope.oneMonthAgo = function oneMonthAgo() {
      var date = new Date;
      date.setMonth(date.getMonth() - 1);
      return date;
    };

    console.log($scope.oneMonthAgo()); # prints Mon Nov 17 2014 11:56:15 GMT-0500
```

What's the deal?

Comment: maybe `$scope.oneMonthAgo` should be declared before `$scope.dateRange` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need to repeat the function name; you also need to define the function before you attempt to use it in dateRange.

```
$scope.oneMonthAgo = function() {
  // ... function stuff here
};

$scope.dateRange = { /* Can make calls to $scope.oneMonthAgo() here */ }
```

Comment: Mephoros is correct.  Remember that $scope is just a fancy javascript `Object`

Comment: This helped for me to.

Answer (score 1):

1.You need to define oneMonthAgo before you use it 
2 new Date() instead new Date

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('homeCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.oneMonthAgo = function oneMonthAgo() {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setMonth(date.getMonth() - 1);
    return date;
  };

  $scope.dateRange = {
    before: $scope.oneMonthAgo(),
    after: new Date()
  };



});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>


<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="homeCtrl">

    DateRange:
    <br/>{{dateRange | json}}
  </div>
</div>
```